# How to skip protractor+jasmine tests specific to browsers

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor, cross-browser

Assume that I've automated 25 tests and executing in multiple browsers like chrome, firefox, IE, Edge & Safari. All tests (25) are executing well on Chrome. In Firefox, Only 20 tests are running fine due to few protractor APIs are not supported. Similarly IE can execute only 23 tests.

I would like to skip the test only for browsers, which are not supported for particular test? Is there any way available?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `protracotr.conf` file for each browser with specific `suites` where will be specified what tests should run. And execute in one time all `protractor.conf` files.

```
//protractor.chrome.conf
export let config: Config = {
...
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
  },

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  specs: [
    '../test/chrome/**/*.js'
  ]
};
```

and

```
//protractor.ie.conf
export let config: Config = {
...
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'internet explorer',
    shardTestFiles: true,
    maxInstances: 1
  },

  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  specs: [
    '../test/ie/**/*.js'
  ]
};
```

in your `package.json`:

```
{
...
  "scripts": {
    "test:all": "npm run test:chrome && test:ie",
    "test:chrome": "protractor ./config/protractor.chrome.conf.js",
    "test:ie": "protractor ./config/protractor.ie.conf.js",
     ...
  },
...
}
```

Comment: How does it solve the problem? for ex. in Spec A, test x,y, z are available. all tests are running fine in chrome. But test y is not running on Firefox due to certain protractor APIs. I want to skip test execution for test y. How can I make testY to run for chrome and skip for firefox?

Answer (score 0):

With jasmine2 you can filter tests using a regular expression. Maybe you can add something like @chrome, @ie to your tests and then only run those ones by passing the grep flag:

```
it('should do stuff @ie @chrome', function() {
  ...
});
```

Then run protractor passing the grep flag:

```
protractor conf.js --grep='@ie'
```